# React Native App Crashes on Start

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, homebrew, watchman

Totally new to React Native.

Having installed `brew`, `watchman`, `node`, and `react-native`, when I'm trying to run a newly initiated app, it crashes upon being opened, as well as it has no icon:

[The app icon on springboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjhrR.png)

I have tried uninstalling all of the packages several times but to no avail.

**EDIT:** Added the logs: https://paste.ee/p/VoBO6

Comment: Check out React Native [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). Did you install XCode Command Line Tools as well?

Comment: Did you run app with command  `react-native run-ios`, if so you should attach the console log in your question.

Comment: @Harlan I have added the logs as a paste.